# Outputting all class variables in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, class, variables

I'm following a tutorial on Python classes. I want to output all class variables, but raise_amount doesn't show up for some reason. Here's my class definition along with one instance, emp_1:

```
class Employee:
    
    raise_amount = 1.04
    
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
    
emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Schafer', 50000)
```

These 2 statements do the same thing, but neither displays raise_amount:

```
print(vars(emp_1))
print(emp_1.__dict__)
```

```
{'first': 'Corey', 'last': 'Schafer', 'pay': 50000}
{'first': 'Corey', 'last': 'Schafer', 'pay': 50000}
```

Is there a newer way to output the class variables (Python 3.7)? The above statements worked in the video, but it's from 2016. I can still reference raise_amount (see below), just can't see it when outputting all the class variables.

```
print(emp_1.raise_amount)
```

```
1.04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir)** function:

```
print(dir(emp_1))
```

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to distinguish between "user-defined" attributes and builtin ones, but if you want to exclude *magic methods*, you can use list comprehension:

```
def get_public_attrs(instance):     
    return [attr for attr in dir(instance) if not attr.startswith('_')]

print(get_public_attrs(emp_1))
['first', 'last', 'pay', 'raise_amount']
```

Comment: Plese don't both answer a question **and** mark it as a duplicate

Comment: @DeepSpace Why?

Comment: TLDR If it's a duplicate, mark it as such. If it is not, answer it. If it's a duplicate and you can provide a better answer, mark as duplicate and answer the original question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: @DeepSpace that link just states *what* I should do, not *why* I should do it.

Comment: Any way to print only user defined functions that includes raise_amount? dir(emp_1) works but includes all pre-set variables.

Comment: @sobrio35 see my update